# Cannot alter column to change data type because inherited column

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I created a table named `trackings` and many parttioning children tables, they are named `trackings_pt_...`.

The partition tables `trackings_pt_...`  inherit from the `trackings` table.

I would like to change the column `id` for all of them (both parent and children tables) from `integer` to `bigint`.

```
Alter table trackings alter column id set data type bigint;
```

I'm faced with

```
ERROR: cannot alter inherited column "id"
```

Please help me resolve it.

Postgres version:
PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5), 64-bit

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5), 64-bit

Comment: With Postgres 11 you should be using [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) where you can easily do that

Answer (score 4):

You must have tried to alter the data type on the child table, because it works on the parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE inh_parent (id integer NOT NULL, val text NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE inh_child () INHERITS (inh_parent);

CREATE TABLE inh_child2 (id integer NOT NULL) INHERITS (inh_parent);
NOTICE:  merging column "id" with inherited definition

ALTER TABLE inh_parent ALTER id TYPE bigint;  -- works

ALTER TABLE inh_child ALTER id TYPE int;      -- fails
ERROR:  cannot alter inherited column "id"
```

`trackings` must be inheriting from another table. Run `\d trackings` in `psql` to check that.